# Webex Productivity Tools - Disable Automatic Updates

Tags: windows-7-x64, webex

We´re Using the "Webex Productivity Tools" in our Environment.
Our users are working without any Admin rights.
Every week I have to install manual updates since the users are unable to do this themselves but are still receiving popups requesting they install them.
One of the users are wondering if it's possible to disable these automatic updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Productivity Tools automatic updates can be disabled at the site configuration level. You'll want to log in as an admin to https://[sitename].webex.com/admin (replace [sitename] with your sitename), then click Common Site Settings -> Productivity Tools. From there, uncheck 'Automatically update Productivity Tools when new versions are available' and you should be good to go.